# Google authentication gcloud.beta.ml.jobs.submit.training

Tags: api, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

i trying to submit a job in the google ml cloud.

```
  gcloud beta ml jobs submit training readlips_resnet1 \
  --package-path=trainer \
  --module-name=trainer.run \
  --staging-bucket=gs://xxxxbucket/ \
  --region=us-central1 \
  --scale-tier=BASIC_GPU \
  -- \
  --input_path gs://xxxxbucket/readlips/m1/readlips-test-1-{}.tfrecords \
  --input_path_test gs://xxxxbucket/readlips/m1/readlips-test-1-6.tfrecords \
  --board_path gs://my-first-bucket-mosnoi/readlips/m1/TFboard3_readlips_resnet \
  --model_dir gs://xxxxbucket/readlips/m1/models3 \
  --filenameNr 2 \
  --save_step 1000 \
  --display_step 100 \
  --max_steps 2000 \
  --batch_size 20 \
  --learning_rate 0.001 \
  --keep_prob 0.8 \
  --layers 3 \
  --hidden 150 \
  --rnn_cell LSTM \
  --optimizer ADAM \
  --initializer  graves \
  --bias -0.1 \
  --gpu
```

i am getting the next error

```
 Job [readlips_resnet1] submitted successfully.
 INFO    2017-02-28 12:14:48 +0200       unknown_task            Validating job requirements...
 INFO    2017-02-28 12:14:48 +0200       unknown_task            Job creation request has been successfully validated.
 INFO    2017-02-28 12:14:49 +0200       unknown_task            Job readlips_resnet1 is queued.
 ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml.jobs.submit.training) UNAUTHENTICATED: Request
 had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token,
login cookie or other v alid authentication credential. See
 https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

i do not know how to set those 2 access token, i have looked in the documentation, i tryed  gcloud beta init --account= and gcloud beta auth application-default login --client-id-file=.
i have create the credentials, api key, OAuth 2.0 client IDs and Service account keys, but i do not know where to put it in order to my job to be run.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable the Cloud API for your project, create a service account, and download a private key as JSON. The service account is most important in this case, as the error seems to point to invalid credentials.

You can read more detail on the "[Creating and Managing Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)" documentation.

Run the following command

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

It should show you the list of service accounts associated with your GCP. 
Verify the service account using the following code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient import http
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
my_project_id = 'my_current_project_id' # change according to your 
project id
projects = 'projects/' + my_project_id
ml_client = discovery.build(
    'ml',
    'v1',        
    requestBuilder=http.HttpRequest,
    credentials=credentials)
projs = ml_client.projects()
response = projs.getConfig(name = projects).execute()
SERVICE_ACCOUNT = response.get('serviceAccount')
print('Your Service Acc:', SERVICE_ACCOUNT)
```